# At which position does the regex fail?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, syntax, substring

I need a very simple string validator that would show where is first symbol not corresponding to the desired format. I want to use regex but in this case I have to find the place where the string stops corresponding to the expression and I can't find a method that would do that.
(It's got to be a fairly simple method... maybe there isn't one?)

For example if I have regex:

```
/^Q+E+R+$/
```

with string:

```
"QQQQEEE2ER"
```

The desired result should be 7

Comment: Personally I'm hoping there's some way to create a Regexp object and then ask it to "try and match" a string, and then tell it to record the first time it was unable to find a match. That sounds like a "general" way, since the regex engine presumably knows when it failed, though I was reading [this](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/4/3/exploring-rubys-regular-expression-algorithm) and it looks like even that might not be a reliable approach with all the optimization tricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idea: what you can do is to tokenize your pattern and write it with optional nested capturing groups:

```
^(Q+(E+(R+($)?)?)?)?
```

Then you only need to count the number of capture groups you obtain to know where the regex engine stops in the pattern and you can determine the offset of the match end in the string with the whole match length.

As @zx81 notices it in his comment, if one of the elements can match the next element (example Q can match the element E), things become different.

Let's say that Q is `\w` (and can match E and R). For the string `QQQEEERRR` the precedent pattern will give only one capturing group (the greedy `\w+` matches all) when `^(\w+)(E+)(R+)$` will give three groups: `QQQEE`, `E`, `RRR`

To obtain the same result you need to add an alternation:

```
^((?:\w+(?=E)|\w+)(E+(R+($)?)?)?)?
```

In the alternation, the case where E exists must be tested first, and only if this branch fails (with the lookahead), then the other branch where E doesn't exist is used.

Thus the full pattern can be rewritten like this to deal with this specific case:

```
^((?:Q+(?=E)|Q+)((?:E+(?=R)|E+)((?:R+(?=$)|R+)($)?)?)?)?
```

Perhaps could you take a look to the gem [amatch](http://flori.github.io/amatch/) too.

Comment: +1 Nice. `/^(Q+(E+(R+($)?)?)?)?/.match( 'QQQQEEE2ER' )[0].length` gives the `7` which the OP is looking for. If it returns a value equal to the length of the test string, then the match was successful.

Comment: Thanks, however it can be a little fastidious to build the pattern by hand, and almost impossible to build it automatically from a raw pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your example Matt, but I've run into a problem with this -- you can't always detect a match based on length match, consider this "email": `mynamegmail.com` since the whole string is actually a valid username first capture group would catch it all. Here is my example
`/([A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+(@([A-Z0-9a-z\-]+(\.([A-Za-z]{2,4}($)?)?)?)?)?)?/.match( 'mynamegmail.com' )[0].length => 15`

Comment: @JackWatson: I understand your problem, but in this case, you only need to check the existence of the capture group that must match the @. You can extract the length later. Keep in mind that this pattern matches always any strings.

Comment: @zx81: it's indeed the same approach but without zero-width assertions and only with real characters of the tangible universe of strings.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes your solution is definitely more efficient, no question about that. :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Looking at it again, it now seems to me that your solution, while terrific in this precise case of testing the tokens in `Q+E+R+`, breaks down if the tokens are not mutually exclusive, as for instance with `^(\w+(E+(R+($)?)?)?)?`, which as you know is a common situation. On `QER`, `Q`, `QE` etc, this shows that only one group is set, while in fact all tokens of `^\w+E+R+` participate in the match. In this situation my solution still works, so it seems to me it might be more general. Though I will remember yours for mutually-exclusive cases. What do you think?

Comment: @zx81: Ok, I will take a look at this later. I need to sleep.

Comment: @zx81: Indeed, good point! I added a way to solve the problem.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte A bit of a hack (I'm sure you'll agree) but that does it, well done. :)

Comment: @zx81: All the answers here are hacks (except Cary Swoveland who is a little more reasonable). But I admit that the pattern loses some of its (relative) lightness.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Hey Caz I hope you know I'm not trying to be insulting here. :) My point is that if you have more overlapping patterns somewhere in QER, that's more work... Whereas my solution still works. Don't get me wrong, I still love the lightness of your solution for when the tokens are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @zx81: Please be reassured, I don't take it as an insult. The comment was pertinent.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh good, it's so hard to gauge tone in writing. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting task that can be accomplished with a neat regex trick:

```
^(?:(?=(Q+)))?(?:(?=(Q+E+)))?(?:(?=(Q+E+R+)))?(?:(?=(Q+E+R+$)))?
```

We have four optional lookaheads checking various parts of the pattern and capturing the partial matches to Groups 1, 2, 3 and 4 incrementally.

1. Group 1 contains `Q+` if it can be matched, in your example `QQQQ`.
2. Group 2 contains `Q+E+` if it can be matched, in your example `EEE`.
3. Group 3 contains `Q+E+R+` if it can be matched, in your example `nil`.
4. Group 3 contains `Q+E+R+$` if it can be matched, in your example `nil`.

In your code, check which is the last Group that is set by testing `!$1.nil?`, `!$2.nil?` and so on.

The last one set gives you the length that is matchable, so in your example `$2.length` gives you the `7` you wanted.

Incidentally, the fact that Group 2 is the last one set also tells you that we fail on `R+`.

Comment: It's taken me quite awhile to read through your answer (+1) and I'm still not finished.  You see, I had a quick look at your profile, decided to have a look at your worst (ha!) and best answering experiences at SO, and am now part way through [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)...

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ha, I too love reading other people's posts. :)

Answer (score 2):

For your example, you could do the following.

**Code**

Change your regex from:

```
    /^Q+E+R+$/
```

to

```
R = /^(Q*)(E*)(R*)/
```

and then apply the following method to the string:

```
def nbr_matched_chars(str)
   str.scan(R).flatten.reduce(0) {|t,e| return t if e.nil?; t+e.size } 
end
```

`str` matches the original regex if and only if `nbr_matched_chars(str) == str.size`.

**Examples**

```
nbr_matched_chars("QQQQEEE2ER") #=>  7
nbr_matched_chars("QQQQEEEERR") #=> 10 (= "QQQQEEEERR".size)
nbr_matched_chars("QQAQQEEEER") #=>  2
```

**Explanation**

To see why this [evidently :-)] works, we can look at the results of invoking [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan), followed by [Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
"QQQQEEE2ER".scan(r).flatten #=> ["QQQQ", "EEE" , nil ]
"QQQQEEEERR".scan(r).flatten #=> ["QQQQ", "EEEE", "RR"]
"QQAQQEEEER".scan(r).flatten #=> ["QQ"  , nil   , nil ]
```